# Modelling probability problems by Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For one of my courses, we have to think about how we could model certain problems with the help of Markov chains. Most are straight-forward, but I find it difficult to choose the right states and transitions to model the next two situations:

- Two people pick three different numbers at random between 1 and 10. Construct a Markov chain (with 6 or more states) to determine the probability that they picked two or more identical numbers.
- Set up a Markov chain to determine the probability that two or more persons have the same birthday among a group of n people.

In both cases, the purpose is not to calculate the exact probability, but to construct a Markov chain that would be suitable to determine the probability (possibly with the help of hitting probabilities, steady state distributions etc.). What would be a good/smart choice for the states and transitions for each of the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You can think of it as a process by, at each step, allowing each player to choose their next number, so after any step, $n$, both players have $n$ numbers.

The states could then be the possible ordered pairs, $(n,m)$, of step number and number of matches so far:

\begin{align}
S = \{& (0,0), \\
& (1,0),\quad (1,1) \\
& (2,0),\quad (2,1),\quad (2,2), \\
& (3,0),\quad (3,1),\quad (3,2), \quad (3,3)\}. \\
\end{align}

(2) You can think of this one as a process by starting with an empty set of people and then with each step adding one new person to it. 
We have one (absorbing) state, $M$ say, representing the case where the set contains at least one matching/shared birthday. The other states are $0,1,\ldots,n$, and here, step $k$ represents
the case where the set has $k$ members and no matching birthdays. So,

\begin{align}
S = \{M,0,1,\ldots,n\}.
\end{align}